# Can I pass a variable string into the "Value" attribute for a HTML input tag?

Tags: python, html, flask

sorry if this is a simplistic question or demonstrates some misunderstanding of HTML, this is my first time using it. If there's any missing info or stuff I should have included in the question, I'm happy to provide it.

I have a python program, app.py, and it calls and renders an HTML page. That HTML page contains a few inputs and I understand how to place a given string as the default value for the input with the Value attribute.

This is the html:

```
<form action="/new" method="post">
    <label for="qty_wheels">Number of wheels:</label>
    
    <input type="text" name="qty_wheels" value = "Qty_Wheels"     />
    <label for="flag_color">Colour of flag:</label>
    <input type="text" name="flag_color" />
    <input type="submit" class="button">
</form>
```

Where "Qty_Wheels" is written though, I want to place a string I've passed in from the python end.

This is the python call for this html page:

```
return render_template("buggy-form.html", Qty_Wheels = given_qty)
```

I've passed in the Qty_Wheels string here, and I want to print the value of that in the input. Is this possible and how can I do it? I've tried a lot of different syntax variants, but I can't find how I get it to interpret it as a string and print the content.

Comment: You are inconsistent in your usage of the slash on `<input>`. Not a fix  but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flask's templates use the `{{ val }}` syntax:**

Put the double curly brackets around `Qty_Wheels`:

```
<form action="/new" method="post">
    <label for="qty_wheels">Number of wheels:</label>
    
    <input type="text" name="qty_wheels" value = "{{ Qty_Wheels }}"     />
    <label for="flag_color">Colour of flag:</label>
    <input type="text" name="flag_color" />
    <input type="submit" class="button">
</form>
```

For more on Flask templates see: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/templates/

Comment: Hi, I gave this a try and the box appears empty still. I know it's probably an issue with my passing in of the variable.but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it was an issue outside of what I described in the question but with that resolved your solution does work, thank you very much.